# golang ini file output with flags

Tags: go, ini, flags

I would like to write an application config in go using flags and then have it writeout into an .ini file.

I've done this with JSON files, but can't figure out the ini.

Any suggestions?

Ini file will look like so:

```
Name=*flag input

[Output]
Mode=*flag input

[Input]
BaseCX=*flag input
BaseCY=*flag input
Common=*flag input
```

Can't figure it out.

Comment: You may do it manually, but there is no out-of-the box support for `ini` files in the standard lib. Check out the [go-ini/ini](https://github.com/go-ini/ini) project.